# Need string to increment with counter in vb

Tags: vb.net, while-loop, counter, increment

```
 Public Class Form1
Private Sub btnCreateRhombus_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCreateRhombus.Click

    'Declarations
    Dim userInput As Integer
    Dim rowCount As Integer = 1
    Dim spaces As Integer = 0
    Dim stars As String = "****"

    'user imput
    userInput = Convert.ToString(TxtNum1.Text)

    'Calculations

    drawStarSub(userInput, stars, rowCount)

    drawSpaceSub(userInput, stars)

    'Output

End Sub

Sub drawStarSub(userInput As String, stars As String, rowCount As String)

    Dim count As Integer = 1

    While count <= userInput
        stars = stars & vbNewLine & stars

        count = count + 1
    End While

    'Output

    lblResult.Text = Convert.ToString(stars)

End Sub

Sub drawSpaceSub(userInput As Integer, stars As String)

End Sub
End Class
```

What the program needs to do is draw a parallelogram
If the user types 3 there are 3 rows, 4 there are 4 rows etc... up to 11.
I am required to make a sub for the row increments and the space increments.

Where I am having trouble is getting the "stars" string to increment itself with the counter in the "drawStarSub". Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Clearly explain `I am required to make a sub for the row increments and the space increments.`

Answer (score 0):

Try substituting `stars = stars & vbNewLine & stars` with this

```
stars = stars & vbCrLf & stars
```

That worked for me. Personally I would have used a `For` loop instead of the `While` loop but it's no big deal.